# How can I filter out stackoverrun.com using Google (Or Firefox if not)?

Tags: google-search, firefox

I usually search on Google for Stack Overflow answers and there are a lot of "fake" pages that I want to filter, like stackoverrun.com and so on.... I really hate them.

There is any way to filter those websites, putting them in a list on any Google Configuration as Google user logged in? Or similar, but in Firefox?

I don't want to be declaring what sites I don't want in my search.

Comment: I don't know a way to do so on server side. The only way that I know is using a plugin for your web browser (e.g. Firefox or Chrome). It is an open source project called "Personal Blocklist". https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/personal-blocklist/

Comment: By *"Google user"* do you mean *"Google Chrome user"* (as it seems to be contrasted to another web browser, Firefox)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen hi! No, logged in google without any browser corcern. I don't use chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Use Google's `site:` filter  eg `site:stackoverflow.com`

More Google search syntax usage at Google Help - [Refine web searches](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en)

Comment: Thats what im using but I though it can be predifined in some google (logged user) config

Comment: I've no idea - but that's not the question you asked. Please edit to be more specific.

Comment: done! edited already